# How do I move a string into resource strings.xaml?

Tags: c#, android, xaml

I am really green in regard to developing Android apps using Xamarin with Visual Studio Community. I have strings defined in my C# code. I understand the strings should be in a resource, i.e., strings.xml. Apparently, if I were using Eclipse & Java, there is a function in the IDE to solve this issue. But I am not. In addition, I have a string in a button widget in xaml namely 'Read Me' thus:

Button

android:text="Read Me"

How do I:

1. get the strings embedded in the c# code into strings.xml

2. get the strings in the xaml into strings.xml

3. reference the strings in c# code 
once they are in strings.xml?

Since I am so green, specific examples would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

3) Have you tried the [GetText](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/localization/#GetText_Method) method?

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit the string.xml file and add something like: 
   string name="ControlFileName">controlFile.txt

   build the activity to update Resources.values

   to access the string from c# code:

   string conFile = this.GetString(Resource.String.ControlFileName);

   string conFile will now be controlFile.txt

I hope this helps the greenhorns out there.